# Insert every (n*5)-th line in one text file with the n-th line from another text file

Tags: insert, sed, apt

I'd like to insert each (n*5)-th line in file1 with the content of the n-th line from file2 (n=0..m). Example:
file1

```
1: blabla1
2: blabla2
3: ddddd
4: sddddd
5: ffffff
6: hhhhh
...
```

file2

```
1: name1
2: name2
3: name3
...
```

Result

```
1: name1
2: blabla1
3: blabla2
4: ddddd
5: sddddd
6: ffffff
7: name2
8: hhhhh
...
```

Is there any "sed" or "awk" one liner to do that?

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -re ':a;Rfile1' -e 'x;s/^/./;/.{5}/!{x;ba};s/.*//;x' file2
```

or:

```
sed -e '1~5{h;Rfile2' -e 'd};2~5{x;p;x}' file1
```

However I've noticed there might be an end-of-file problem with the second solution.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
awk '
NR==FNR{a[NR]=$2;next}
{print ++x": "$2;while(++i%5){print ++x": "a[i]};print ++x": "a[i]}' file1 file2
```

#### Output:

```
1: name1
2: blabla1
3: blabla2
4: ddddd
5: sddddd
6: ffffff
7: name2
8: hhhhh
```

Answer (score 1):

bash solution. I added a few lines to file1 for effect

```
exec 4<file1
while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "$line"
    for i in {1..5}; do
        IFS= read -r line <&4 || break
        echo "$line"
    done
done < file2 | cat -n
exec 4<&-
```

```
 1  name1
 2  blabla1
 3  blabla2
 4  ddddd
 5  sddddd
 6  ffffff
 7  name2
 8  hhhhh
 9  gggg
10  iiii
11  jjjj
12  kkkk
13  name3
14  llll
```

This produces the same output:

```
awk 'NR%5 == 1 {getline f2 < "file2"; print f2} 1' file1 | cat -n
```

Obviously, piping to `cat -n` is not integral to the solution, just for illustration.